# How to process specific files and link them?

Tags: makefile, codeblocks

I've found something for compiling text file as string variable:
Code:

```
objcopy --input binary --output elf64-x86-64 --binary-architecture i386 test.txt test.o
```

and i want to do it for each ./included_text/*.abc and then each of these files link.
I've find pre/post build steps but i can't find anything which will help me. Or you can explain how to do whole makefile if it's easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
output:

text_files:= $(wildcard *.txt)

text_objects:=$(addsuffix .o,$(basename $(text_files)))
objects=$(text_objects) $(other_objects)


%.o: %.txt
    objcopy --input binary $(OBJCOPY_FLAGS) $< $@

output: $(objects)
    echo linking $@ from $^
    #ld ....
```